# How do I get the iOS App launch event by clicked icon from home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My app has a lot of launch way,like universal links, deep links,remote notification,spotlight.

When app activated by these functions,
I can get event by `userActivity.activityType`
in`application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:`

Now I want to get the iOS App launch event by clicked icon from home screen, how can I do?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the *default* launch scenario. Other, special scenarios (notification, links) always give you something extra in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions`

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc):

> **launchOptions**
>
> A dictionary indicating the reason the app was launched
>   (if any). **The contents of this dictionary may be empty in situations
>   where the user launched the app directly**. For information about the
>   possible keys in this dictionary and how to handle them, see Launch
>   Options Keys.

So the solution is to check the `launchOptions`. The dictionary is empty when user launched the app directly.

Comment: Thanks, but doc written "may be".
What happens when the user clicks on the home page and launchOptions have the value?

Answer (score 1):

In [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc), you get a dictionary with launchoptions. If this launchOptions dictionary is nil, it means the app is launched using click on app icon.

Also, if your app is in suspended state, and app icon is clicked, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not going to get called but rather [applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623076-applicationwillenterforeground) will get called.